# Why <body>, <head>, <html> tags and some others are not considered as HTML of <code> tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to add `<body>, <head>, <html>` into `<code>` tag but it does not consider it as its HTML. Other Tags like `<div>, <a>, <p>, <b>, <i>, <textarea>` e.t.c are working.

Here is the Fiddle:

[***Fiddle Link***](http://jsfiddle.net/eqnK4/)

Comment: Such markup is simply invalid and grossly violates the document model of HTML. Asking why HTML is defined that way calls for speculation. The question does not describe what the intended purpose is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`<html>`, `<body>`, and `<head>` are expected to be the root of the document, so they will be ignored when they are not at the root.

When you add `<code>` at the root, the browser inserts `<html><body>` before it automatically because it knows it is supposed to be there, and then it will ignore the others because they are not at the root.

That means that what actually ends up in the parsed DOM tree is this:

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <code>
      <div>
        Foo!
      </div>
    </code>
  </body>
</html>
```

Thus, when your code runs, it gets everything inside of `<code>`.

If you want to display all if this as text, you should be encoding the HTML as text, using `&lt;` and such, and then use `.text()` instead.

Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/eqnK4/1/

Comment: A subtlety here is that jQuery's `html()` uses the DOM's `innerHtml` which is not guaranteed to be identical to the source HTML, even if it is valid.

Comment: but man every tag should be supported! :/ what w3.org do? they made `<code>` for adding codes!

Comment: @AspiringAqib Updated. If that doesn't work, please expand your question with more info on what you want.

Comment: @loganfsmyth i am satisfied with your answer but it seems imposibble because i am making something that it will need an ajax call to get <code> tag html and save it to db but it does not consider it as HTML so, it will not save correctly! Note: User enters code and then it saves the HTML.

Comment: @AspiringAqib If you are receiving content that is HTML, you will need to escape the `<` and `>` characters with their encoded values.

Comment: buddy, try to understand user enters code as `<html><body></body></html>` and then when i retrieve it on any event `$("code").html();` it will not have code. I know about php `htmlspecialchars` but when the code will be transferred without `html, body and head` tags and then there is no use of htmlspecialchars. Sorry! as my question is already answered and i am still not leaving commenting!

Comment: @AspiringAqib I know! You need to use `.text()` and just store it like that. Or write your own code to convert the HTML entities back to tags.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22942/discussion-between-aspiring-aqib-and-loganfsmyth)